# Flash content disappears when the swf is moved from original directory

Tags: flash

I'm developing an application using Flash CS5. The application itself runs successfully when tested with Ctrl+Enter. The problem being the moment I moved that .swf file from the original directory, the content disappears, and the Flash Player shows ellipsis ( ..... literally ) instead of the usual content.

When I moved it back to the original directory, however, it works once more.

I'm stumped. This didn't happen when I developed a flash content with Flash CS3 a year back. Is there something that I have to do? I've searched with keywords "swf content disappears when moved" but everything is about the file itself being gone, not the content inside it

This is a huge problem. I'm developing for AIR, and once the application is installed, the same thing befalls the application

Maybe there's a configuration in my PC that causes this to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. In ActionScript 3 settings in Publish settings change the **Default Linkage** in "Runtime Shared Library Settings" to "Merge Into Code" rather than Runtime Shared Library (RSL). This will allow your SWF to be completely independent